# Issue with program not solving equivalent capacitance (5) in series.

Tags: c

link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eKTh.jpg
I input the values, but the output isn't working, even after i debugged. The question asks the user for the coulombs and voltage and my program "should" compute the coulomb, as well as its sum (assume its in series).

```
#include <stdio.h>
 typedef struct
{
double q;  // charge on the capacitor
double v; // voltage
} CAPACITOR;
// Structure for 5 cpacitors in series

typedef struct
{
CAPACITOR c1;
CAPACITOR c2;
CAPACITOR c3;
CAPACITOR c4;
} CAPACITORS_IN_SERIES;
double equivalentCapacitance(CAPACITORS_IN_SERIES);
void main(void)
{

CAPACITORS_IN_SERIES serCaps;
double eqCapacitance;
// Get input from the user
printf("Please give the charge (Coulombs) and voltage (Volts) for Capacitor             1: \n");
scanf("%lf%lf",&serCaps.c1.q, &serCaps.c1.v);

printf("Please give the charge (Coulombs) and voltage (Volts) for Capacitor   2: \n");
scanf("%lf%lf",&serCaps.c2.q, &serCaps.c2.v);

printf("Please give the charge (Coulombs) and voltage (Volts) for Capacitor 3: \n");
scanf("%lf%lf",&serCaps.c2.q, &serCaps.c3.v);

printf("Please give the charge (Coulombs) and voltage (Volts) for Capacitor 4: \n");
scanf("%lf%lf",&serCaps.c4.q, &serCaps.c4.v);
// Compute the equivalent capacitor
eqCapacitance = equivalentCapacitance(serCaps);

// Display results
printf("Capacitors in series: \n");
printf("Charge (Coulombs)     Voltage (volts)    Capacitance (F)\n");
printf("    Capacitor 1: %15.2e  %15.2f   %15.2e\n",
serCaps.c1.q, serCaps.c1.v, serCaps.c1.q/serCaps.c1.v);
printf("    Capacitor 2: %15.2e  %15.2f   %15.2e\n",
serCaps.c2.q, serCaps.c2.v, serCaps.c2.q/serCaps.c2.v);
printf("    Capacitor 3: %15.2e  %15.2f   %15.2e\n",
serCaps.c3.q, serCaps.c3.v, serCaps.c3.q/serCaps.c3.v);
printf("    Capacitor 4: %15.2e  %15.2f   %15.2e\n",
serCaps.c4.q, serCaps.c4.v, serCaps.c4.q/serCaps.c3.v);
printf("Equivalent capacitance: %.2e\n",eqCapacitance);
}

double equivalentCapacitance(CAPACITORS_IN_SERIES sCaps)
{
// Variable declations
double eqCap;  // Equivalent capacitance
// Instructions
eqCap = sCaps.c1.v/sCaps.c1.q;  // set to 1/C1
eqCap = eqCap + sCaps.c2.v/sCaps.c2.q;  // Adds 1/C2
eqCap = eqCap + sCaps.c3.v/sCaps.c3.q;  // Adds 1/C3
eqCap = eqCap + sCaps.c4.v/sCaps.c4.q;  // Adds 1/C4
eqCap = 1/eqCap;  // sets to 1/(1/C1 + 1/C2 ...)
return(eqCap);
}
```

Comment: What is it about the current result that you're unsatisfied with? If all you know is "this code doesn't work" then your question is simply too broad for StackOverflow. Please edit your question to be more specific so that we can attempt to help you find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("Please give the charge (Coulombs) and voltage (Volts) for Capacitor 3: \n");
scanf("%lf%lf",&serCaps.c2.q, &serCaps.c3.v);
//                      ==             ==             Oops
```

Copying and pasting code doesn't work. If you find yourself doing it, you are doing it wrong.